# HTML select multiple option failed

Tags: javascript, css, html, select

I'm trying to use multiple select option in my html page
I'm using materialized css
I used the below code
But it is not working
Can anyone help me with this please

```
<select multiple size='6' name='list[ ]'>
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option selected>Three</option>
    <option>Four</option>
    <option>Five</option>
    <option selected>Six</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I don't think this not working, can you please post the full code ?

Comment: It works for selecting single option only
But i want to select more than one option at a time

Comment: @chung it is a very lengthy code and i don't thin i can post all of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your syntax.
If you are using materialize css, it should work.
http://materializecss.com/forms.html
Go to "select" and check syntax.

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
    <select multiple>
       <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
       <option value="1">Option 1</option>
       <option value="2">Option 2</option>
       <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <label>Materialize Multiple Select</label>
</div>
```

Also initialize select by adding

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').material_select();
});
```